# How to retrieve Java NIO PosixFilePermission during a Files.walkFileTree?

Tags: java, linux, nio

On Unix, `Files.walkFileTree` will callback `FileVisitor.visitFile` with `BasicFileAttributes` which are actually `sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributes$UnixAsBasicFileAttributes`. As the debugger shows, the wrapped `UnixFileAttributes` already contain permission information (`st_mode` field is populated). Is there a (graceful) way to *unwrap* the `UnixFileAttributes$UnixAsBasicFileAttributes` in order to get at least `PosixFileAttributes` so the permissions will be accessible? Reflection does not work for me, but results in an `IllegalAccessError` when trying to invoke `UnixFileAttributes$UnixAsBasicFileAttributes.unwrap`.

Also, I want to avoid to explicitly call `Files.getPosixFilePermissions(file)` for every reported file as this gives roughly 10% overhead for my test cases.

Answer (score 2):

In my Java, there's a package-private method just to unwrap the wrapped attributes. No guarantee that any Java will contain this method. For now this works for me and I hope it does for you too.

[image]

I can call this method with the following code.

You came very close with your attempt at [Java 9: How to retrieve the ctime in FileVisitor.visitFile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46676279/1052284). I simplified it a bit for this question.

```
try {
    Class<?> basicFileAttributesClass = Class.forName("java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes");
    Class<?> unixFileAttributesClass  = Class.forName("sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributes");

    Method toUnixFileAttributesMethod =
            unixFileAttributesClass.getDeclaredMethod("toUnixFileAttributes", basicFileAttributesClass);
    toUnixFileAttributesMethod.setAccessible(true);

    attrs = (BasicFileAttributes)toUnixFileAttributesMethod.invoke(unixFileAttributesClass, attrs);
} catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

For Java 9 and up, the `setAccessible()` checks module permissions, which your module doesn't have. This can be unlocked with the VM option `--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED`.

Comment: In which package is your `UnixFileAttributes` class located? On Windows, `UnixFileAttributes` doesn't seem to be present (Java 11). Hence, my attempt with reflection.

Comment: As you seen in my code, in `sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributes`. This *is* a proprietary package so it indeed may differ for you. (the 'no guarantee' I talked about)