# Java 9: How to retrieve the ctime in FileVisitor.visitFile()?

Tags: java, nio

I'm looking for an efficient way to retrieve the *ctime* information stored in `sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributes` during a `Files.walkFileTree`:

```
Files.walkFileTree(root, EnumSet.noneOf(FileVisitOption.class), Integer.MAX_VALUE, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
  public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    // get ctime from BasicFileAttributes here
  }
}
```

There is a hack for Java 8: reflection can be used to access `UnixFileAttributes.ctime()`. However this code requires to change accessibility of the `ctime()`-method which will fail for Java 9 with an `InaccessibleObjectException`.

```
Class<?> basicFileAttributesClass = Class.forName("java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes");
Class<?> unixFileAttributesClass = Class.forName("sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributes");

Method toUnixFileAttributesMethod = unixFileAttributesClass.getDeclaredMethod("toUnixFileAttributes", basicFileAttributesClass);
toUnixFileAttributesMethod.setAccessible(true);

Method cTimeMethod = unixFileAttributesClass.getDeclaredMethod("ctime");
cTimeMethod.setAccessible(true);

Object unixFileAttributes = toUnixFileAttributesMethod.invoke(unixFileAttributesClass, attributes);
((FileTime)cTimeMethod.invoke(unixFileAttributes)).toMillis();
```

I'm still hoping to have missed some NIO utility method which does the job.

Comment: Which operating system is still? I'm curious why can't you use attrs.creationTime()?

Comment: The problem is on Linux/OSX. The API gives you only `BasicFileAttributes`, because `sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributes` is plattform-dependent.

Comment: BasicFileAttributes defines the creationTime method to expose the file creation time where possible. There should be no reason to be poking around in the implementation classes.

Comment: The creationTime is not the Unix ctime ("changed-time").

Comment: Thanks, @AlanBateman, I would accept this as an answer that NIO currently does not support this.

Comment: Ah okay, you are looking at the last change time, there is no support in the API for that except by using 
Files.readAttributes(file, "unix:ctime"). It potentially could be exposed in a type safe manner via PosixFileAttributes but has never been a priority (I don't recall it coming up on nio-dev either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java 9 and up, the `setAccessible()` checks module permissions, which your module doesn't have. This can be unlocked with the VM option `--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED`.